# Extracting index.php?dir=foo/bar/&file=bar2.jpg to foo/bar/bar2.jpg

Tags: linux, bash

I have a lot of files with names like:

```
index.php?dir=IOP%2FFOO%2FBAR%2F&file=ScanImage001.jpg
```

After replacing `index.php?` with nothing `%2F` with '`/`', `dir=` with noting and `file=` with nothing:

```
IOP/FOO/BAR/ScanImage001.jpg
```

Now I want to rename first file to the second as well as create directories.

How can I do that?

Comment: `%2F` is control character or literal string?

Comment: @jimmij - %2F is the url encoding of a slash (`/`). http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp. When written to the disk as a filename it's literal.

Comment: What files are you referencing when you say "rename first file to the second"?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have it in one variables `$url`

```
 short=$(echo $url | sed -e s,%2F,/,g -e s,^index[^=]*=,, -e s,.file=,,)
 mkdir -p $(dirname $short)
 mv $url $short
```

- `mkdir -p` will create directory, along with all paths.
- `$(dirname $short)` will give you the dirname part of $short (e.g. `IOP/FOO/BAR` )

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.jpg 
  do 
  b=$(echo $i | sed 's/.*dir=//' | sed 's/%2F/\//g' | sed 's/&file=//')
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$b")
  mv "$i" "$b"
done
```

The line with `sed` invocations store the full path the filename should get.
The `mkdir` line creates the directory including intermediate directories and doesn't complain if they already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If `%2F` is literal string (not control character) then you can try this little script:

```
for file in index*.jpg; do

dir1=$(grep -Po '.*dir=\K[[:alnum:]]*' <(echo "$file"))
dir2=$(grep -Po '.*dir=[[:alnum:]]*%2F\K[[:alnum:]]*' <(echo "$file"))
dir3=$(grep -Po '.*dir=[[:alnum:]]*%2F[[:alnum:]]*%2F\K[[:alnum:]]*' <(echo "$file"))
filename=$(grep -Po '.*file=\K.*' <(echo index.php\?dir\=IOP%2FFOO%2FBAR%2F\&file\=ScanImage001.jpg))

echo mkdir -p $dir1/$dir2/$dir3            #remove echos
echo mv $file $dir1/$dir2/$dir3/$filename  #at the beginning of the line

done
```

Remove both `echo` commands if you like what you see on the screen.